# Should i use a Template Framework?

Tags: c#, templates, frameworks, t4

I was given a project in which the admin is allowed to fill out a form( choosing from 6 types of forms) each has their own structure and design, and have it save this form and be displayed in the slide show that the project is running.

In a previous version of this project the slides in the slide show were html pages, so i would have that when the admin clicks "Save Form" or "Submit" buttons that it would save it as a html page with a specified layout inside a specific folder, when i asked whats something i could use to go about this, i was told to look up Template Frameworks(this is coded in C# by the way) so with that said, i have been researching the built in template framework of visual studios, T4, is this a viable route to go about doing what I would want to do? Please explain if you can.

This project is being built using MVC

Comment: Everybody has the struggle that he is not choosing the best possible way. I known that feeling, but I think the question is really too broad for stack overflow. It will cost only primary opinion based answers.

Comment: "each has their own structure and design" - template much, how? Anyway, I would likely not choose a template (and definitely not TT for this), but instead model around interfaces *after* choosing a "framework".

Comment: All i want to really know is if T4 will be able to do what i require of it

Comment: The requirements are not specified clearly.

Comment: by "Each has their own structure and design" i mean the 6 types of slides, Information, Announcements, Birthdays, Work anniversary, Clients, New Employees

Comment: Okay .. and how are they to be "created"? What will they be created as? Are they to be generated to-code or to-HTML, etc? How will the resulting objects (however they are created) be wired up? How will the different types (generated or not) unify?

Comment: by created i mean that the Admin will choose what slide he/she wants and have a form appear with the corresponding text fields for the information required, and when filled out, the Admin will click Save and i guess that i will have it saved as a .html, im not familiar with generate to-HTML, what do you mean how will they be wired up?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is not a Web Project, you can use this project: http://razorengine.codeplex.com/ to render .html files

It is open source and simple:

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

UPD1: Answer to your question about T4: yes, with T4 you can create HTML. But, it is better to use Razor  , Razor is created for HTML templating, it is mainstream and a common way.

UPD2: Ok, you said that it is a MVC project. Then, inside your Controller use the write the following method:

```
public void RenderViewToFile(string viewName, object model, string filePath)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);

        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);

        var rendredContent = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, rendredContent);
    }
}
```

Next, create views (.cshtml files) for your templates. Create models with your data and use the method above in order to save it in server side folder.

Comment: this project is using MVC

Comment: Then, why not to use MVC to render .html files? Just save data somewhere, and render it. T4 is for code generation. If you have a C# and you want to create html, then use Razor and MVC

Comment: How to create website with MVC actually is a big topic, you should search web with '.NET MVC tutorial' and start to learn this technology step by step

Comment: i've created a website before using mvc but Template Framework is new to me